# Remove subview from other method

Tags: ios, swift, view, uiblureffect, uivisualeffectview

I initialize UIVisualEffectView from one method and need to remove it with other method.

```
func showBlur() {
    let blurEffect: UIBlurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
    let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    // ...
}
func destroyBlur {
    // i can’t destroy via remove from superview it here, blurView was initialized in showBlur()
}
```

I’ve tried to initiate blurView not in method but in class… there is problems with init() in UIViewController.

I’ve tried to find that view in view.subViews, but i’ve got no luck.

I’ve tried to set tag to UIView but can’t find that tag lately in subView list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create property to store UIVisualEffectView on the beginning od the class:

```
var blurView: UIVisualEffectView!
```

and in `showBlur()` function, sto the effect in this variable:

```
let blurEffect: UIBlurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
```

and in destroyBlur() call:

```
blurView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand the question correctly, the problem is that you don't have a reference to blurView outside of showBlur().

If this is the problem then you need to create a class member (class property) for blurView.

You might want to make this an optional property since it seems it might or might not get set later.

Something like this might work

```
var blurView:UIVisualEffectView?
```

Later in your code:

```
func showBlur() {
    let blurEffect: UIBlurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
    blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    // ...
}
func destroyBlur {
    blurView!.removeFromSuperview();
}
```